# How to display data from the SQLite database in the Home `GridView` layout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to display data from the SQlite database in the Home `GridView`, In the `DisplayDetails()` method while using `ItemsSource` to pass the data, error says that Grid doesn't contain a defenition for `ItemsSource` and no accessible extension method accepting an argument of type 'Grid'. 
Please find the `Home.xaml` grid layout and `Home.xaml.cs` class for more details

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="soccerapp.Home" BackgroundColor="White" Title="Home">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid x:Name="gridDisplay" Padding="10">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!-- Use Grid.Column to specify column -->

            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding FullName}" BackgroundColor="#92f459"/>
            <Label x:Name="HomeLabel"  Text="Home Page is here" TextColor="White"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="Small"></Label>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Below is the `Home.xaml.cs`

```
namespace soccerapp
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Home : ContentPage
    {
        public SQLiteConnection conn = null;
        public PlayerDetails playermodel;
        public Home(string parameter1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            HomeLabel.Text = parameter1;
            conn = DependencyService.Get<Isqlite>().GetConnection();
            conn.CreateTable<PlayerDetails>();
            DisplayDetails();
        }

     public void DisplayDetails()
        {

            var details = (from x in conn.Table<PlayerDetails>() select x).ToList();
            gridDisplay.ItemsSource= details; 
        }


    }
```

I have added the `PlayerDetails` model class:

```
namespace soccerapp
{
    public class PlayerDetails
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        public string SoccerPosition { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    }


}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts#populating-a-bindable-layout-with-data

Comment: Will have a look on the above links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you try to bind a `list<>` to a `Grid`?  Set `gridDisplay.BindingContext` to a model should work.

```
public void DisplayDetails()
{

    var details = (from x in conn.Table<PlayerDetails>() select x).ToList();
    PlayerDetails playermodel = details[0];
    gridDisplay.BindingContext = playermodel;
}
```

**Update:**

Codes in model:

```
public class PlayerDetails : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    string fullname;

    public PlayerDetails( ) {

    }

    public string FullName
    {
        set
        {
            if (fullname != value)
            {
                fullname = value;

                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FullName"));
                }
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return fullname;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

> ViewModels generally implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface,
>   which means that the class fires a PropertyChanged event whenever one
>   of its properties changes. The data binding mechanism in Xamarin.Forms
>   attaches a handler to this PropertyChanged event so it can be notified
>   when a property changes and keep the target updated with the new
>   value.

**Update 2:**

I checked your project and I found the problem is in your `xaml` code:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid x:Name="gridDisplay" Padding="10">

        ...

    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
<Label x:Name="HomeLabel"  Text="Home Page is here" TextColor="White"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="Small"></Label>
```

You put a label outside the `ContentPage.Content` and set `VerticalOptions` `HorizontalOptions` equals `CenterAndExpand`, so it will overlapping all the content page and you can't see anything in Grid.

And you set the `textcolor = white` so you will not see the text of the label under a white backgroundColor.

So , the solution is remove this label or move this label into content page. You can put this label into Grid or somewhere else.

Comment: Yes I will try that and reply you soon.

Comment: @JackHua...The error has gone, but now the records are not displaying in the Home screen.

Comment: @soccerway What is record? You only bind a `FullName` in your xaml and is `FullName` in your playermodel?

Comment: Yes FullName in my playermodel, anyway will double check the name again

Comment: @soccerway Is your model implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface as I updated in my answer?

Comment: Got a question ? Why do we need to implement that, I have other fields like mobile, position which also need to display in Home screen

Comment: @soccerway You can have a look at this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm) about INotifyPropertyChanged . Sure if you have other properties and set binding properly, they will show in the screen. I also updated my answer about INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: But I don't have `INotifyPropertyChanged` class in my project.

Comment: @soccerway It's a system interface and you don't have to write it by youself. using  System.ComponentModel. And in my answer, i already wrote a model with Fullname for you.

Comment: I have added your code, build the solution again, click on the Navigate to Home button, system didn't display the player names in home. I have registered two player record already in to the app

Comment: @soccerway I uploaded my sample [here](https://github.com/XfHua/Gird-binding), have a look at it may helps.

Comment: Hua, check in my project with your answer here [projectlink] (https://gitlab.com/k.vinodmathew/k-vinodmathew)

Comment: Hua : Could you please have look ?

Comment: @soccerway Yes, I'm looking into it and I will update you if I find anything.

Comment: ...Will check that, If I have multiple `players` should the system automatically display the records in multiple Grid in Home Page ? Or should I need to handle that ?

Comment: Wow..its working now...I believe i have got 3 records added, but its displaying only one record..I doubt where the Grid are overlapping one over the other...

Comment: @soccerway If you have multiple players, you should binding the right property of each player. Like play1.text = {binding fullName1}, play2.text = {binding fullName2}. And fullName1 and fullName2 are the property in your model. Not the overlapping problem.

Comment: Where should we binding the property of each player like  `play1.text = {binding fullName1}, play2.text = {binding fullName2}` ? Is that in `Home.xaml` file or in PlayerDetails model class ?

Comment: @soccerway Set binding in Home.xaml as you do right now(the same as binding full name). And in your PlayerDetails model, you should have these properties. I think you should change the code of `PlayerDetails playermodel = details[0];`, this line only takes the information of first player. You can cover all the player's information here and put them into playermodel.

Comment: Hua, Wonderful !, I will try that and let you know, you are such an awesome helper !

Comment: Hua, I have tried many ways in Binding the playermodel into the grid Layout, following your code, but i couldn't see all players in the Home screen

Comment: @soccerway Ok, I will check it.

Comment: @soccerway Is the number of players always same or it will change sometimes?

Comment: It will keep on adding while register and will reduce on delete